# AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'LSTM'

Tags: lstm

for some reason LSTM does not exist for me which I am wondering why it is not working. I have seen no one got an error like this, so I am assuming that it
is a silly mistake, but I am not sure. My code has all of the inputs I have done so far plus the error is at the very end. Does anyone have a reasonable explanation why? Thanks

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Copy of pytorch.ipynb
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

from torchtext.datasets import Multi30k
from torchtext.data import Field, BucketIterator

import spacy
import numpy as np

import random
import math
import time

Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

Original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1s9di7jS0uAaYhvtz-blJbapKjLa9u4q3
"""

pip install torchtext

pip install -U spacy[cuda101]

!python -m spacy download en

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

from torchtext.datasets import Multi30k
from torchtext.data import Field, BucketIterator

import spacy
import numpy as np

import random
import math
import time

!python -m spacy download de

spacy_de = spacy.load('de')
spacy_en = spacy.load('en')

def tokenize_de(text):
    """
    Tokenizes German text from a string into a list of strings (tokens) and reverses it
    """
    return [tok.text for tok in spacy_de.tokenizer(text)][::-1]

def tokenize_en(text):
    """
    Tokenizes English text from a string into a list of strings (tokens)
    """
    return [tok.text for tok in spacy_en.tokenizer(text)]

SRC = Field(tokenize = tokenize_de, 
            init_token = '<sos>', 
            eos_token = '<eos>', 
            lower = True)

TRG = Field(tokenize = tokenize_en, 
            init_token = '<sos>', 
            eos_token = '<eos>', 
            lower = True,
            batch_first=True)

train_data, valid_data, test_data = Multi30k.splits(exts = ('.de', '.en'), 
                                                    fields = (SRC, TRG))

print(f"Number of training examples: {len(train_data.examples)}")
print(f"Number of validation examples: {len(valid_data.examples)}")
print(f"Number of testing examples: {len(test_data.examples)}")

print(vars(train_data.examples[0]))

SRC.build_vocab(train_data, min_freq = 2)
TRG.build_vocab(train_data, min_freq = 2)

print(f"Unique tokens in source (de) vocabulary: {len(SRC.vocab)}")
print(f"Unique tokens in target (en) vocabulary: {len(TRG.vocab)}")

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

BATCH_SIZE = 128

train_iterator, valid_iterator, test_iterator = BucketIterator.splits(
    (train_data, valid_data, test_data), 
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
    device = device)

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, emb_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.hid_dim = hid_dim
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_dim, emb_dim)
        
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(emb_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout = dropout)
        
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
    def forward(self, src):
        
        #src = [src len, batch size]
        
        embedded = self.dropout(self.embedding(src))
        
        #embedded = [src len, batch size, emb dim]
        
        outputs, (hidden, cell) = self.rnn(embedded)
        
        #outputs = [src len, batch size, hid dim * n directions]
        #hidden = [n layers * n directions, batch size, hid dim]
        #cell = [n layers * n directions, batch size, hid dim]
        
        #outputs are always from the top hidden layer
        
        return hidden, cell

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, emb_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.hid_dim = hid_dim
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(output_dim, emb_dim)
        
        self.rnn = rnn.LSTM(emb_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout = dropout)
        
        self.fc_out = nn.Linear(hid_dim, output_dim)
        
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
    def forward(self, input, hidden, cell):
        
        #input = [batch size]
        #hidden = [n layers * n directions, batch size, hid dim]
        #cell = [n layers * n directions, batch size, hid dim]
        
        #n directions in the decoder will both always be 1, therefore:
        #hidden = [n layers, batch size, hid dim]
        #context = [n layers, batch size, hid dim]
        
        input = input.unsqueeze(0)
        
        #input = [1, batch size]
        
        embedded = self.dropout(self.embedding(input))
        
        #embedded = [1, batch size, emb dim]
                
        output, (hidden, cell) = self.rnn(embedded, (hidden, cell))
        
        #output = [seq len, batch size, hid dim * n directions]
        #hidden = [n layers * n directions, batch size, hid dim]
        #cell = [n layers * n directions, batch size, hid dim]
        
        #seq len and n directions will always be 1 in the decoder, therefore:
        #output = [1, batch size, hid dim]
        #hidden = [n layers, batch size, hid dim]
        #cell = [n layers, batch size, hid dim]
        
        prediction = self.fc_out(output.squeeze(0))
        
        #prediction = [batch size, output dim]
        
        return prediction, hidden, cell

class Seq2Seq(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, device):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.device = device
        
        assert encoder.hid_dim == decoder.hid_dim, \
            "Hidden dimensions of encoder and decoder must be equal!"
        assert encoder.n_layers == decoder.n_layers, \
            "Encoder and decoder must have equal number of layers!"
        
    def forward(self, src, trg, teacher_forcing_ratio = 0.5):
        
        #src = [src len, batch size]
        #trg = [trg len, batch size]
        #teacher_forcing_ratio is probability to use teacher forcing
        #e.g. if teacher_forcing_ratio is 0.75 we use ground-truth inputs 75% of the time
        
        batch_size = trg.shape[1]
        trg_len = trg.shape[0]
        trg_vocab_size = self.decoder.output_dim
        
        #tensor to store decoder outputs
        outputs = torch.zeros(trg_len, batch_size, trg_vocab_size).to(self.device)
        
        #last hidden state of the encoder is used as the initial hidden state of the decoder
        hidden, cell = self.encoder(src)
        
        #first input to the decoder is the <sos> tokens
        input = trg[0,:]
        
        for t in range(1, trg_len):
            
            #insert input token embedding, previous hidden and previous cell states
            #receive output tensor (predictions) and new hidden and cell states
            output, hidden, cell = self.decoder(input, hidden, cell)
            
            #place predictions in a tensor holding predictions for each token
            outputs[t] = output
            
            #decide if we are going to use teacher forcing or not
            teacher_force = random.random() < teacher_forcing_ratio
            
            #get the highest predicted token from our predictions
            top1 = output.argmax(1) 
            
            #if teacher forcing, use actual next token as next input
            #if not, use predicted token
            input = trg[t] if teacher_force else top1
        
        return outputs

INPUT_DIM = len(SRC.vocab)
OUTPUT_DIM = len(TRG.vocab)
ENC_EMB_DIM = 256
DEC_EMB_DIM = 256
HID_DIM = 512
N_LAYERS = 2
ENC_DROPOUT = 0.5
DEC_DROPOUT = 0.5

enc = Encoder(INPUT_DIM, ENC_EMB_DIM, HID_DIM, N_LAYERS, ENC_DROPOUT)
dec = Decoder(OUTPUT_DIM, DEC_EMB_DIM, HID_DIM, N_LAYERS, DEC_DROPOUT)

model = Seq2Seq(enc, dec, device).to(device)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-c6e5fcab540b> in <module>()
     10 
     11 enc = Encoder(INPUT_DIM, ENC_EMB_DIM, HID_DIM, N_LAYERS, ENC_DROPOUT)
---> 12 dec = Decoder(OUTPUT_DIM, DEC_EMB_DIM, HID_DIM, N_LAYERS, DEC_DROPOUT)
     13 
     14 model = Seq2Seq(enc, dec, device).to(device)

<ipython-input-73-36ea9d0e0d8d> in __init__(self, output_dim, emb_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout)
     13         self.embedding = nn.Embedding(output_dim, emb_dim)
     14 
---> 15         self.rnn = rnn.LSTM(emb_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout = dropout)
     16 
     17         self.fc_out = nn.Linear(hid_dim, output_dim)

AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'LSTM'
```

Comment: Can you try nn.LSTM?

Answer (score 0):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-c6e5fcab540b> in <module>()
     10 
     11 enc = Encoder(INPUT_DIM, ENC_EMB_DIM, HID_DIM, N_LAYERS, ENC_DROPOUT)
---> 12 dec = Decoder(OUTPUT_DIM, DEC_EMB_DIM, HID_DIM, N_LAYERS, DEC_DROPOUT)
     13 
     14 model = Seq2Seq(enc, dec, device).to(device)

<ipython-input-73-36ea9d0e0d8d> in __init__(self, output_dim, emb_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout)
     13         self.embedding = nn.Embedding(output_dim, emb_dim)
     14 
---> 15         self.rnn = rnn.LSTM(emb_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout = dropout)
     16 
     17         self.fc_out = nn.Linear(hid_dim, output_dim)

AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'LSTM'
```

At line 15: you can see its self.rnn = rnn.LSTM
It should be self.rnn = nn.LSTM

Best!